# Error handling & workarounds allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include is disabled on the server

Tags: php, file-get-contents, getimagesize

I've got several functions in my php app that relay on calls to file_get_contents(), file_put_contents, and getimagesize().

The problem is that when allow_url_fopen an allow_url_include are disabled in php.ini I'm getting errors on these critical functions.

> Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is
>   disabled in the server configuration in
>   /home/content/.../html/_sites/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php
>   on line 2534

What are the options for working around these issues?

**EDIT**: These are all local files on the same webserver as the calling php script. Is there a preferred method for reading/writing file contents?

Comment: If [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is enabled on the server you could transfer it to the local file system and operate on the file locally. If it's not enabled, you're pretty stuck.

Comment: EDIT: These are all local files on the same webserver as the calling php script. Is there a preferred method for reading/writing file contents?

Comment: Uhm, how about using their file-system local paths then instead of http: URLs?

Comment: @RegEdit if they `are all local files on the same webserver`, why are you using paths that require `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled? Just use local file system paths and none of this will be an issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use curl to get remote pages.  You can store the results of the curl request to a variable and echo() in place of using the url wrapper to fetch content.

In theory, you could also eval() the returned data.   But running remotely fetched PHP code is a ENORMOUS security risk, any PHP code included in this way can literally do anything you can.  **DON'T DO IT!** The same goes for allow_url_include too

Comment: Thanks Gordon. These are all local files on the same webserver as the calling php script. Is there a preferred method for reading/writing file contents?

Comment: If the files you want to include are on the same server, then just include() or fopen() them directly.  No need for going through a URL and adding the overhead that doing it that way would involve.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Gordon, I was mistakenly calling the file as http instead of ABSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your webserver, you may have to find your php.ini file, for example:

```
/etc/php5/apache/php.ini
```

And use these options:

```
; http://php.net/allow-url-fopen
allow_url_fopen = On

; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = Off
```

If your using someking of hosting account, these options may be interactively available at a control panel.

The second solution might be to use cURL. I suppose you were trying to call getimagesize with an URL. Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```